# How to dll export a function template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, dll, dllexport

I have a template function with its definition defined in a `header.h`
I want to export an instantiation of this function template. This is how I am trying to do so:

header.h

```
template<class T>
void my_function(T& x)
{
    // generic implementation with x
}
```

exports.h

```
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

exports.cpp

```
#include "exports.h"
#include "header.h"
template DLL_EXPORT void my_function(int& x);
```

Doesn't look like my DLL is exporting anything.
Visual Studio says: "Function definition for "my_function" not found" in `exports.cpp`

Also, if I change the line in `exports.cpp` to:

```
template DLL_EXPORT void my_function<int>(int& x);
```

I'm also not able to get it to work!

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:
Ok, false alarm. This does actually work! I was doing the dumpbin /exports my_dll.dll command on the wrong dll!!!

Comment: A template function needs to be fully defined in the header file anyway, so making it available in the DLL is kind of redundant.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I understand. However, this dll will be used in a .NET application

Comment: Then you're going to need an `extern C` function to avoid name mangling anyway.  I'd just create such a function in exports.cpp and have it call your template function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, false alarm. This does actually work! I was doing the dumpbin /exports my_dll.dll command on the wrong dll!!!

It looks like you don't even need to explicitly write the template parameter out either - it'll be inferred.